# Not able to access the container app via UI:Azure

Tags: azure, containers, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

I created the Container App where i would like to access from its website using host url
My container app into the vnet and it is having specific  resource groups and and it contains specific NSG rules
Also, I have created and configured the private DNS zone in which I create a Virtual Network Link associated to VNET,
than I added a dns record set with name *.[same container app address] and container app ip address

When i tied to access the container app using app url i am not able to access it is showing the below  error

`{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /","error":"Not Found"}`

when i close ad reopen the url again got one more error

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3yRm.png)]

I deleted entire app and created newly got the one more error

[image]

Any help will be needed, Thankyou.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've  resolved this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. it will help others  with the same problem. Just a reminder :)

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT it resolved my issue, I am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried to check same in my environment and got the below results*

*I created the virtual network with subnets*

[image]

*After that created the container app environment*

[image]

*If I check the application URL in the browser I am not able to access because I did not set the private dns zone record set
created the private dns zone and linked with the virtual network*

[image]

*I have added the dns record with container IP address to access the web*

*When I check in the command prompt I am able to see the that my container app URL is working*

```
nslookup app-container.icycliff-187ffXXXXXXXXX.io
```

[image]

*When check in the browser using app URL I am able to get application*

[image]

*NOTE:*

*1). After creating private dns zone must add the dns record with container app static IP address*

*2). 404 error message when website content has been removed or moved to another url*

*3). server responsible for the website is not running or the connection is broken*

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Komali Annem I will follow the steps that you mentioned and will get back to you.

Comment: its working fine I forgot to add the static IP o the container app in the dns records, Thankyou for the answer.